# area under curve of exponential integral

Tags: improper-integrals, area

I could use some help interpreting the result for
$$ \int_{0}^\infty y^2 e^{ay} dy $$

which my textbook says = $-2 / a^3$.

I can see how partial integration leads to
$$ \left[\frac{e^{ay}}{a}(y^2 - \frac{2y}{a} + \frac{2}{a^2})\right]\rvert_{y=0}^\infty$$

and then I suppose this leads to
$$ (\infty -\infty + \infty) - (0 - 0 + \frac{2}{a^3}) = -\frac{2}{a^3} $$?

The result in the textbook matches a calculation with a<0 in matlab, but I don't really see how:

- a negative result can represent an area under a curve that seems positive everywhere to the right of 0?
- such a small result can represent this area to $\infty$, even when positive, from an exponential curve?

Comment: Isn't the result nonnegative if $a$ is negative?

Comment: For the small result, it is possible, just like the integral of $\frac{1}{x^2}$ from $1$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Note that the integral is only equal to $-2/a^3$ if $a < 0$, in which case the infinities in your boundary term become zeroes and it all works out. For $a \ge 0$ the integral is divergent, which is why you get those infinities.